# Exporting images to XML SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Is there a way to export images to XML from SSRS?

Images column invisible when I open XML file via excel.

When export my report to excel directly no problem i can see the images.

Any suggestion?

Thanks,

Comment: You really can't do this directly, but some more detail on what you're trying to accomplish might be useful to see if there's a suitable alternative method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this because the XML renderer is a data renderer that writes to a text file, much like the CSV renderer.  That means that it doesn't attempt to export certain formatting and visual elements.  Excel won't ever be able to load them because they weren't saved in the file in the first place.  Just as if you were loading an exported CSV.

The Excel renderer, on the other hand, is a layout renderer which attempts to preserve those visual elements.  Sometimes at the cost of making the data more difficult to work with.

Per the MDSN reference, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd283112.aspx:

> The XML rendering extension returns a paginated report in XML format. The schema for the report XML is specific to the report, and contains data only. Layout information is not rendered and pagination is not maintained by the XML rendering extension.

And https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd255234.aspx:

> The Excel renderer is primarily a layout renderer. Its goal is to replicate the layout of the rendered report as closely as possibly in an Excel worksheet and consequently cells might be merged in the worksheet to preserve the report layout.

XML files themselves are text-based and rarely contain images.  Even with image data stored as Base64, that would not achieve the result of having a column display images when opening in Excel.

One area where XMLs were used to store image data were the 2003 XML Office document formats, which stored them in a `<pkg:binaryData>`element.  There's a chance you could generate such a file using an XLST transformation and a lot of work.  But that is likely beyond the scope of your question, and at that point you would be better served just using the Excel renderer.